# Pytest mock.patch requests AttributeError: does not have the attribute 'json'

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to test an api mock call using `from unittest.mock import patch`. I keep getting an `AttributError` when I include `.json()` in my function's response return (i.e. `return response.json()`).

When I exclude the `.json()` in my return statement, the test passes. I'm pretty new to testing and I can't figure out how to get around this error. Does anyone have an idea of how to get around this by keeping the `.json()` in the return statment?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my code for reference:
`test_pytest.py`

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.foo_helper import get_foo_data

@patch('requests.get',
       return_value={
           "version": "v1",
           "greeting": "Aloha "
       }
       )
def test_get_foo_data(mock_get, mock_json):

    print("Mock_get: ", mock_get())
    print("Mock_json: ", mock_json())
    print("Function: ", get_open_play_data)
    # print("Function call: ", get_foo_data('https://example.com',
    #                                             CONFIG['KEY'],
    #                                             CONFIG['PASSWORD']))

    result = get_foo_data(
        'route', 'key', 'password'
    )
    print("Result: ", result)
    assert mock_get() == result
    assert False
```

`foo_helper.py`

```
import requests

def get_foo_data(route, key, password) -> object:
    # route should be a string
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            route,
            auth=(
                key,
                password
            )
        )
        print("Response: ", response)
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"There was a problem with your request: '{e}'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LuísMöllmann already pointed out, the patching is incorrect. The actual usage was:

```
requests.get().json()
```

But the patching was:

```
requests.get.return_value = {some dict}
```

This means that `requests.get()` will already return `{some dict}` which then fails when `.json()` is called.

#### Solution 1

The dictionary response must be mocked at `requests.get.return_value.json.return_value` and not just the `requests.get.return_value`:

```
@patch('requests.get')
def test_get_open_play_data(mock_get):
    mock_json = {
        "version": "v1",
        "greeting": "Aloha "
    }
    mock_get.return_value.json.return_value = mock_json

    result = get_open_play_data(
        'route', 'key', 'password'
    )
    print("Result: ", result)
    assert mock_json == result
```

### Solution 2 (Recommended)

Don't reinvent the wheel of mocking the `requests` module. Use a library such as [requests_mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/) which does it easily for you.

```
import requests_mock as requests_mock_lib


def test_get_open_play_data_using_lib(requests_mock):
    mock_json = {
        "version": "v1",
        "greeting": "Aloha "
    }
    requests_mock.get("http://route", json=mock_json)  # If you want the mock to be used on any URL, replace <"http://route"> with <requests_mock_lib.ANY>

    result = get_open_play_data(
        'http://route', 'key', 'password'
    )
    print("Result: ", result)
    assert mock_json == result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mock returns a dictionary, not a response object like the original `requests.get` function:

```
@patch('requests.get',
       return_value={
           "version": "v1",
           "greeting": "Aloha "
       }
       )
```

So basically, you're doing:

```
{"version":"v1","greeting":"Aloha "}.json()
```

Hence the error:

> 'dict' object does not have the attribute 'json'

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use the responses library:

```py
import responses

@responses.activate
def test_get_service_connections()
    mocked_response = {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "Service Connection 1",
                "type": "AzureRM",
                "authorization": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "tenantid": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab",
                        "serviceprincipalid": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab",
                        "authenticationType": "spnKey"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Service Connection 2",
                "type": "AzureRM",
                "authorization": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "tenantid": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab",
                        "serviceprincipalid": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890ab",
                        "authenticationType": "spnKey"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }


    responses.add(responses.GET, f'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4&includeDetails=true', json=mocked_response)
```